# Converting an obj sequence to a .bobj fluid sim cache?

Tags: python, export, file-format, fluid-simulation

I'm wondering if there is any way to accomplish turning an obj sequence exported from realflow into a .bobj fluid cache that I could then trick blender into loading as a native fluid sim cache. So far I've managed to find some old (2.4x) docs on a .bobj import script, but nothing on exporting to .bobj files. I can't find anything in the API docs either so far so I'm not feeling to hopeful, but I thought I'd try.

All that I really require is a way to export to the .bobj format (which as I understand is a Binary encoded .obj file). I don't know enough about the internals of these files to write an exporter myself, but I was hoping that there would be something in the API that I could use.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a script to manage obj mesh sequences in blender. This doesn't convert anything to .bobj, but you might want to have a look: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?252844-Script-Meshfoot-OBJ-Sequence-Manager-%28revised-for-Blender-2-66%29

Comment: What export options does realflow have? Have you tried blenders mesh cache modifier? It would appear to work with PC2 and MDD.

Comment: @Gandalf: Tried this, but it loads every frame into the blendfile, which quickly becomes unmanageable for a decent length fluid sim sequence.

Comment: @sambler: Both PC2 and MDD only allow for meshes with the same vertex order on every frame. Fine for rigged meshes, but no good for fluid sim where the mesh is different every frame.